# clean files in changes not staged for commit list git

Tags: git

I have just started using git on a windows machine, when I do

```
git status
```

I see a long list of files listed as changes not staged for commit and I want to clean that up, however any of the

```
git checkout --. or git status clean or git stash -u or git clean -dfx
```

seems to be working. when I re-type git status the long list is still there. Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `git checkout ./` It will remove all your changes

Comment: If the repository you're working with is a Linux or Unix one, and you're on Windows, you may be hitting end-of-line issues. I avoid Windows so I don't have recommendations here, but search for questions involving `.gitattributes` files and CR-LF Windows-style line endings.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri git checkout ./ gives me fatal: can not create directory at '...<some file name with parathesis and underscores>' : invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create and commit a `.gitignore` file in the root folder of your Git repository that lists all of the filetypes Git should ignore.

[See this page for more details.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Here's an example `.gitignore` file that avoids committing executables and jar files to your repo:

```
# exclude all JARs and Executables
*.jar
*.exe
```